# Add multiple products to cart if they are not already in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

In WooCommerce I've implemented **@jtsternberg's** [WooCommerce: Allow adding multiple products to the cart via the add-to-cart query string](http://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/) to allow adding multiple products at once, but I've received many complaints from customers who actually try to use one of the links containing multiple products.

For starters, if the customer clicks checkout and then clicks the browser "back" button, all the item quantities increment. I solved this by redirecting the user to the cart URL stripped of any additional parameters after the add-to-cart behavior completes, but it's not ideal.

What I really want is to check if the item is in the cart first and only add to cart if it isn't there already. Has anyone done something similar?

**Working Update:**
I ended up modifying the code from @jtsternberg to use a completely separate param name in order to avoid conflict with the default add-to-cart behavior. Then I was able to use @LoicTheAztec's suggested code below by wrapping the behavior in a check to see if that new param exists. Here's the full section:

```
function custom_product_link() {
  if (empty( $_REQUEST['multi-product-add'])) {
    return;
  }

  $product_ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['multi-product-add'] );

  foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
    $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $product_id ) );
    $was_added_to_cart = false;
    $adding_to_cart    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    if ( ! $adding_to_cart ) {
      continue;
    }

    $add_to_cart_handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $adding_to_cart->product_type, $adding_to_cart );

    if ( 'simple' !== $add_to_cart_handler ) {
      continue;
    }

    // For now, quantity applies to all products.. This could be changed easily enough, but I didn't need this feature.
    $quantity          = empty( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $_REQUEST['quantity'] );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );

    if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) ) {
      wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity ), true );
    }
  }
  if ( wc_notice_count( 'error' ) === 0 ) {
    // If has custom URL redirect there
    if ( $url = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', false ) ) {
      wp_safe_redirect( $url );
      exit;
    } elseif ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) === 'yes' ) {
      wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
      exit;
    }
  }
}

function check_product_added_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
  if (!empty( $_REQUEST['multi-product-add'])) {
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_key => $cart_item ){
      // if products are already in cart:
      if( $cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id ) {
        // Set the verification variable to "not passed" (false)
        $passed = false;
        // (Optionally) Displays a notice if product(s) are already in cart
        // wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . $btn['label'] . '</strong> ' . __( 'This product is already in your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        // Stop the function returning "false", so the products will not be added again
        return $passed;
      }
    }
  }
  return $passed;
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'custom_product_link', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_product_added_to_cart', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the code you are using you have **`woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`** filter hook inside it, you can use it in a custom hooked function to check if products rare already in cart with something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_product_added_to_cart', 10, 3 );
function check_product_added_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_key => $cart_item ){
        // if products are already in cart:
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $product_id ) {
            // Set the verification variable to "not passed" (false)
            $passed = false;
            // (Optionally) Displays a notice if product(s) are already in cart
            wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . $btn['label'] . '</strong> ' . __( 'This product is already in your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            // Stop the function returning "false", so the products will not be added again
            return $passed;
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and this normally should works with your customization…

> For product quantities, you can use the **`$quantity`** argument with **`$cart_item['quantity']`** in some conditions…

Comment: Wow, this is so much simpler than what I was working on! I'll have to run some tests though, would this interfere with normal add-to-cart behavior, e.g. when a user clicks a product?

Comment: @bhamrick You have to test… I can't tell as it depends on your products, settings … This filter code just avoid customer to add-to-cart 2 times the same item in cart. In general customer doesn't put 2 times the same item in cart, they set/update the quantity… So I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: thank you! This worked great. I ended up changing the param name from the default `add-to-cart` to `multi-product-add`, then I wrapped the `foreach` statement in your code in an `if (!empty( $_REQUEST['multi-product-add']))` block.

Comment: @bhamrick Great, this is a good new as I have seen many times people asking for someway to add multiple products at the same time… Happy it worked!… May be you could update your answer with all that code, I mean the code **jtsternberg** + your customizations and this last snippet. You could do that at the end of your question adding a separation with **Working Update:** title… (just a suggestion, that will be useful to the community). Is better to include in the answer, the code you have used, mention authors credits…