# Avoid add to cart based on specific product in cart on Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, product, custom-taxonomy

From this answer: 
[Max number of items in a cart based on product category in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452739/max-number-of-items-in-a-cart-based-on-product-category-in-woocommerce), 
the following code works well:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );
function only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $total_count = $cart_count + $quantity;

    if ( has_term( 'quantity4','product_cat',$product_id ) && ( $cart_count >= 4 || $total_count > 4 ) ) {
        $passed = false; // Set to false
        $notice = __( "You Chose a Box of 4 Items, Can't Add More", "woocommerce" ); // Notice to display
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'quantity6','product_cat',$product_id ) && ( $cart_count >= 6 || $total_count > 6 ) ) {
        $passed = false; // Set to false
        $notice = __( "You Chose a Box of 6 Items, Can't Add More", "woocommerce" ); // Notice to display
    }
    if( ! $passed )
        wc_add_notice( $notice, 'error' );

    return $passed;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. When the user clicks 'add to cart' and that action makes the total quantity of items in the cart exceed the limit amount set in the code, the page redirects to that single product view and displays the error message. Is there a way to instead keep the user on the same page and display the error message?
2. What I can't figure out is how to BYPASS that code IF a specific product is in the Cart. I've tried several varying options for items ( $in_cart ) or trying to unset( $plugins[$key] ) but I admit to being in over my head.

Simply stated, If Product '123' is in the cart, the above category product quantity limitations in the cart should NOT apply.

Can anyone provide guidance as to what else I should try?

Thank you.

Comment: my apologies. I have edited to hopefully make it clearer. In this case, the 'add to cart' buttons are in a woo product table on a page, so that is maybe why the redirect to the single product view happens. I will test directly on a product to see what happens there. Thank you.

Comment: For Point 1) I don't think that this is possible in a simple way.... For Point 2) check this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035613/3730754 and

Comment: In testing directly on the shop archive page, the same thing happens in that when the add to cart button is clicked (if the cart quantity then exceeds the allowed total) it directs to the single product (and displays the error message). Thank you.

Comment: With ajax add to cart (on archives pages as shop) there is no other way... If not you need to disable ajax add to cart.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I understand the limitations on Item 1. And I'll review that other answer you referenced for Item 2.